# Disabling jQuery UI radio-Button does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to disable jquery radio button? the following doesn't work:

```
<input type="radio" id="myButton" name="myButton" />

$("#myButton").attr({disabled: true});
```

the following disables the button, but it distroy the layout of the button, maybe because its RADIO button:

```
$("#myButton").button("option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: Do you see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zpcRD/)? I can't reproduce...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#myButton").attr('disabled',true);
```

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/eUgdm/

Comment: so you have an other problem in your code. look at the link i attached.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myButton").button({disabled:true});
```